# Keeping tabs with "a href=#sometabname" from scrolling to the anchor with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of vertical tabs about a quarter of the way down my page. They are all visible on page load from the top of the browser window. When you click on a tab, it scrolls down and puts the tab content at the top of the window. I know why it does this, is there anyway to override this behavior so that the tabs change content but the window does not scroll?
Thanks,
Kane

Answer (score 1):

`return false` or use `preventDefault();`

Here's an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tUaqw/

Comment: Im using jQuery Tools tabs, I need a way to add bookmarkable links for the tabs and am already using their overlay functionality and don't want to load 2 different UI scripts... so I have this
$(function() {
        $('html').addClass('js');
        $("#flowtabs").tabs("#flowpanes > div").history();
        $("#flowtabs ul li a").bind('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
         });
    });
 and it's still scrolling...

Comment: I believe your problem is in `$("#flowtabs").tabs("#flowpanes > div").history()` as the click function isn't called with that line uncommented, but is called when I comment that line out. I'm not familiar wit the tabs plugin, but that's where your problem is. http://jsfiddle.net/G5FWn/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out was a issue with the UI, can't give the anchor and the tab itself the same ID. Thanks for your help, yours is the way it should work!